# Finding the maximum sum of 11 elements from 480 elements with constraints

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a panda dataframe with columns that look like this:

```
   ict    |constraint1|constraint2|
 float(x) |     y     |     z     |
```

I have 480 rows in the dataframe, which is currently sorted by `ict`. I need to find the maximum possible sum of the `ict`s of 11 elements, then check if that set fulfils a criteria (e.g. `constraint1` can only equal `b` less than 5 times). If it doesn't fulfil the criteria, I need to find the next biggest possible sum of `ict`s of 11 elements.

I currently have a function `check_ict(list1)` that checks the `ict` of 11 elements that are inputted as a list of dataframe row indexes. I also have a function `check_constraints(list1)` that checks if that same input fulfils the constraints. However I'm struggling to figure out how to find the 'next biggest possible sum of `ict`s'.

As the data is sorted by `ict` already, I know the best possible combination is the 0th-10th row of the dataframe. The next best combination is the 0th-9th row + the 11th row. But after that, things get tricky. There's no obvious way to know if `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12]` is bigger, or `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11]`. And no obvious way to know what's the biggest after that.

How do I continuously find the next best possible combination? There are `10^21` possible combinations of a set of 11 elements from 480 elements, so brute forcing is definitely not an option.

Comment: Could you explain more about those criteria that must be fulfilled? If they are simple rules I guess a dynamic approach can help, otherwise formulating a mathematical optimization model might be a good idea.

Comment: Like dhasson suggested, mathematical optimisation is the way to go for these sorts of problems. People have developed general algorithms and packages for this type of problem. Use them. You wouldn't try to write your own database, or spreadsheet, or whatever. So why would you try to implement your own optimiser, other than for teaching yourself that these are hard problems. Absolutely do your own thing as a way of understanding what is going on. In some special cases, there are special -purpose algorithms that are fantastic. Then try using the right tools for the job.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, use mathematical optimisation to solve this. If possible, linear optimisation is a simpler subset of mathematical optimisation under the condition that the constraints can be written as linear. In that case, a package like `pulp` might be able to help you.

Some example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp as pl

# Generate some data
np.random.seed(42)
n_rows = 20

constraint1_capacities = {
    'a': 3,
    'b': 20,
    'c': 5
}

constraint2_capacities = {
    'x': 5,
    'y': 10,
    'z': 15
}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ict': np.random.rand(n_rows),
    'constraint1': np.random.choice(list(constraint1_capacities), n_rows),
    'constraint2': np.random.choice(list(constraint2_capacities), n_rows),
})

print(df)

# Solve the actual problem
take_best = 11

# Create variables: x_i denotes that the i'th element is included, we create
# one for each row in the dataframe
x = [pl.LpVariable(f"x_{i:02}", cat=pl.LpBinary) for i in range(len(df))]

# Initialise the problem
problem = pl.LpProblem("choices", pl.LpMaximize)

# Define the objective function as the sum of all x_i * ict_i
problem += pl.lpSum(x * df.ict.values)

# Constraints:
# In total, at most `take_best` rows can be taken:
problem += pl.lpSum(x) <= take_best

for key, _max in constraint1_capacities.items():
    # x_i * constraint1_i <= _max for every potential key
    problem += pl.lpSum(x * (df.constraint1 == key).values) <= _max

for key, _max in constraint2_capacities.items():
    # x_i * constraint2_i <= _max for every potential key
    problem += pl.lpSum(x * (df.constraint2 == key).values) <= _max

problem.solve()
print(pl.LpStatus[problem.status])

print("Choose rows: ")
for v in problem.variables():
    if v.varValue != 0:
        print(v)
```

which yields

```
Optimal
Choose rows: 
x_01
x_02
x_03
x_07
x_08
x_09
x_11
x_12
x_16
x_18
x_19
```